# Adjacency matrix from Pandas edgelist dataframe for undirected graphs

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
data1 = { 'node1': [1,1,1,2],
     'node2': [2,3,5,4],
     'weight': [1,1,1,1], }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['node1','node2','weight'])
```

I want to create an adjacency matrix from pandas dataframe.The dataframe has edgelist of the undirected graph

OUTPUT:

```
0 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
```

My code:

```
def adjmat():
    print 'begun creating adjen mat'
    data = sc.loadtxt('training.csv', dtype='str', delimiter=',',skiprows=1)
    data = sc.transpose(data)
    row1 = data[1].astype(int)
    row2 = data[2].astype(int)
    weight=data[3].astype(int)
    n=0
    n1=0
    n2=0


    n1=max(row1)
    n2=max(row2)

    if n1>n2:

        Amat=sc.zeros((n1,n1))
        #matrix=sc.zeros((n1,n1))
        n=n1


    else:
        Amat=sc.zeros((n2,n2))
        #matrix=sc.zeros((n2,n2))
        n=n2


    for i in range(0,len(row1)):

        row=row1[i]
        col=row2[i]

        Amat[row-1][col-1]=weight[i]

    i_lower = np.tril_indices(n, -1)
    Amat[i_lower] = Amat.T[i_lower]



    return Amat
```

I am looking for code which will be scalable.right now I am deaing with dataset which has 100,000 nodes and this code is not able to handle such large dataset.

Comment: Why you dont use networkx for this task?

Comment: @enyard how to do in networkx?

Comment: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_dataframe.html

Return a graph from Pandas DataFrame.

Comment: @enyard i want an adjacency matrix as output

Comment: Sorry if I get something wrong, but why has your adjacency -matrix with a 4x4 input a 5x5 output?

Comment: @Markus because it is a edgelist and 1-5 is a edge

Comment: @Code_ninja First generate the graph, and after the adjacency matrix:
https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.linalg.graphmatrix.adjacency_matrix.html

Answer (score 1):

```
Using networkx.....

data1 = { 'node1': [1,1,1,2],
 'node2': [2,3,5,4],
 'weight': [1,1,1,1], }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['node1','node2','weight'])       
G=nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df1,'node1','node2','weight')

Adjtraining = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)

print Adjtraining.todense()

output

[[0 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0]]
```