# Extracting Undirected graph from pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, graph, networkx

I have a directed graph stored in a dataframe, each line is edge from nodes in Columns A > B and B < A. For each edge, I have some attributes, as quantities associate to those edges.

Example

```
A  B  Quantity Attr1 Attr2 ..
1  2  10       5     4
1  3  8        9     6
2  1  5        4     2
...
```

I would like to compute the net value of quantities, like the graph would undirected.

As example: from the two edges 1 > 2 and 2 > 1 I would like to compute an undirected edge, where the Quantity is a function of the attributes  - example :

```
A   B Quantity  Attr1  Attr2 ... 
1   2 (10 - 5)  (5-4)  (4-2)
```

I thought I could approach this problem by iterating on the lines of the dataframe, with two for loops:

```
// pseudo-code
for i, nodeA in enumerate(df['A']):
    for j, nodeB in enumerate(df['B']):
        if nodeA == nodeB:
           quantity = df['A'][i]['Quantity'] - df['B'][i]['Quantity']
           // write new row on a new dataframe, representing the undirected graph
```

Is there another approach I could use in pandas to do it in place ?
Example:

```
// pseudocode

df.apply( lamdba x : computeNetValues(x) if x.A == x.B )
```

E.g. these answers suggest NetworkX - I wonder if I can do it in pandas, before working on graphs

[Adjacency matrix from Pandas edgelist dataframe for undirected graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47602655/adjacency-matrix-from-pandas-edgelist-dataframe-for-undirected-graphs)

[Construct NetworkX graph from Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207872/construct-networkx-graph-from-pandas-dataframe)